# how do I connect to my mac using afp from kubuntu

Tags: macos, kubuntu, netatalk

I have a kubuntu machine.

I want to connect to a mac using AFP.
I've installed the netatalk package in kubuntu.

Now what?

EDIT:
Let me clarify.  My main desktop machine is a kubuntu system.  I have some downloaded podcasts and music on a macmini that I want to access from my Kubuntu desktop.  They are shared and available to other mac systems on the network.  I'm just not sure how to access them from kubuntu

Comment: Wait, you WANT to connect using AFP?

Comment: You should be able to "bonjour" Kubuntu or simply connect using "Command"K connect to server. In my environment I installed Samba in Ubuntu 10.04 and configured that as a target. I have always had trouble connecting reliably from a Mac to anything other than another Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:

https://sites.google.com/site/alexthepuffin/home

According to that page:

> afpfs-ng is a client for the Apple
>   Filing Protocol (AFP) which will let
>   you mount and access shared volumes
>   from Mac OS X (or netatalk) to Linux,
>   BSD and Mac OS X systems.

Perfect, that's what I am wanting!

Comment: Glad you worked this one out. I wonder why it's working for me?

Answer (score 0):

Also install the `avahi-daemon` package. This is 'Bonjour' for Linux. It'll help you go in the other direction as now your Kubuntu box will show up like so in the Finder:

[image: avahi]

Once this is done, restart both the `netatalk` and `avahi-daemon` services. Do this by opening a terminal and doing:

`$ sudo service netatalk restart`

and

`$ sudo service avahi-daemon restart`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Already done that.  There is a little more to it than this though. But I have this part working.

Comment: OK, just putting it out there. Good luck with it. FWIW: with the packages mentioned (that you have) I have no probs going both directions b/w OS X and Ubuntu. Direct ethernet connection (no router). Perhaps this is a Kubuntu specific thing although that doesn't make much sense.